# How to detect end of file with dd?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, dd

I created a 10MB test file:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=file.txt count=1024 bs=10240
```

Then, I wrote the script below to copy this file in chunks. But looks like dd is not detecting the EOF and it always returns 0, so the while loop continues forever.

```
#!/bin/sh

block_size=1048576
count=0
retval=0
while true
do
        dd if=./file.txt of=other.txt bs=${block_size} seek=${count} skip=${count} status=none
        retval=$?
        if [[ $retval -ne 0 ]]; then
                break
        fi
        count=$((count + 1))
done
```

So, how can I get dd to return a difference code when it goes past EOF?

Comment: Edit its source code and recompile.

Comment: You need to remove `status=none` and check `stderr` for the string `0+N records in`, where `N` is the number of bytes in the partial read at end of file.

Comment: @AFH The exact string is locale-dependent. In such cases I temporarily [override localisation settings](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87763/108618): `LC_ALL=C dd …`

Comment: BTW, the effect of `bs=...` is already that it copies the file in chunks, so if all you want to achieve is to copy the file in chunks, you don't need an additional script. (The question doesn't tell us *why* you want to do this, so it may be an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: Note: `[[` doesn't work in `sh` (it works in `bash` though), your script doesn't work as-is in the first place. Use `[` with `sh`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you need this contraption; maybe for learning purpose. OK then, here's more complex contraption:

```
#!/bin/bash

block_size=1048576   # must be a plain number, without any suffix
count=0
while true
do
   retbytes=`dd if=./file.txt bs=$block_size skip=$count count=1 status=none |
             tee >(dd of=other.txt bs=$block_size seek=$count status=none) |
             wc -c`
   [ "$retbytes" -eq "$block_size" ] || break
   count=$((count + 1))
done
```

Your original script uses `sh` and `[[`. This doesn't work. In my version `[` is enough where I need it (`sh` would understand it) but I need `bash` anyway because of `>(…)` syntax elsewhere.

You may not have noticed but your script processes the entire `file.txt` in the first pass because you didn't tell `dd` to stop after the first chunk. (Note `dd` *does this in chunks*, i.e. the sole first `dd` you run does what you want your entire script to do). Later in the loop consecutive `dd`-s overwrite again less and less (because they skip more and more); every time till the end of `file.txt` though. They work is completely useless (unless the input file changes in the meantime). I think your intention was what `count=1` does.

This is how my script works:

1. It uses separate `dd`-s for reading and writing.
2. `tee` forks the output of the reading `dd`. One copy goes to the writing `dd`.
3. The same data gets to `wc -c`, this tool tells the number of bytes it got.
4. The loop is terminated if this number doesn't match our block size.

Note `$block_size` must be in a format that allows comparison to the output of `wc`. Therefore it must be a plain number without any suffix, despite the ability of `dd` to understand some suffices in `bs=` option.